# Trying to use a for loop that cycles through a list of dataframes to compute various summaries

Tags: r, for-loop

Say I have a big dataset called `fulldata` with 3 columns called a, b and c as such:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  a = rnorm(4, 10), b = rnorm(4, 6), c = 1
  )

df2 <- data.frame(
  a = rnorm(6, 10), b = rnorm(6, 9), c = 2
  )

df3 <- data.frame(
  a = rnorm(8, 8), b = rnorm(8, 9), c = 3
  )

fulldata <- rbind(df1, df2)
fulldata <- rbind(fulldata, df3)
```

And I also have subsets based on the value of c such that `df1` are rows where c = 1 ... and so on 3. I have vectors referencing these subsets and column names as such.

```
c_values <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
columns <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Essentially I want to create 5 number summary tables for each column a to c and each subset, like you would get with summary(x) + a mean with columns for min, q1, median, etc all the way to mean. Another column indicating the c value for the subset and also another column indicating which column (a, b or c) is being summarised. Finally one where there is no subset based on c value but the fulldata.

Edit: I'm sorry I tried to format this table into the question but it didn't appear after I posted it

```
for (column in columns) {
  summary1 <- c(summary(df1$columns), mean(df3$columns))
  summary2 <- c(summary(df2$columns), mean(df3$columns))
  summary3 <- c(summary(df3$columns), mean(df3$columns))
} #and then bind the summaries together somehow

for (c_value in values) {
  for(column in columns)
} #bind the whole table together
```

In practice, there are far more than 3 subsets and 3 column names and so I want to be able to cycle through them with a quick loop, hence the vector names from before but I cant seem to get the syntax to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you would like the output to look like but I think you might be better off using a grouped summary instead of a for-loop.

In the example below, I define a function to create a summary (tweak to your liking, e.g. by including the mean) and then apply it to each column:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(4, 10), b = rnorm(4, 6), c = 1
)

df2 <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(6, 10), b = rnorm(6, 9), c = 2
)

df3 <- tibble(
  a = rnorm(8, 8), b = rnorm(8, 9), c = 3
)

fulldata <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)

quantile_df <- function(x, probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) {
  tibble(
    value = quantile(x, probs, na.rm = TRUE),
    quantile = probs
  )
}

fulldata |> 
  reframe(
    across(c(a, b), quantile_df, .unpack = TRUE),
    .by = c
  ) |> 
  select(c, quantile = a_quantile, a = a_value, b = b_value)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>       c quantile     a     b
#>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0.25  8.89  5.14
#> 2     1     0.5   9.19  5.93
#> 3     1     0.75  9.54  6.52
#> 4     2     0.25  9.38  8.68
#> 5     2     0.5   9.84  9.03
#> 6     2     0.75 10.8   9.39
#> 7     3     0.25  7.67  8.03
#> 8     3     0.5   7.87  9.45
#> 9     3     0.75  8.47 10.3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can then reshape/pivot the data to change what is in the columns and rows.